Mockito: "Wanted but not invoked" error when verifying interactions with a mock in JUnit 5 test
I am writing a unit test for a class that has two dependencies of the same type, ExternalISBNDataService, in the StockManager class.
I'm trying to test that my StockManager correctly uses the databaseService before falling back to the webService for retrieving book data. However, I'm getting the following error:
Wanted but not invoked:
dataService.lookup("0140177396");
-> at StockManagementTests.databaseIsUsedIfDataIsPresent(StockManagementTests.java:54)
Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock.

Here’s my code:
StockManager Class:
package com.java.tdd.locator;

public class StockManager {
    private ExternalISBNDataService databaseService;
    private ExternalISBNDataService webService;

    public StockManager(ExternalISBNDataService databaseService, ExternalISBNDataService webService) {
        this.webService = webService;
        this.databaseService = databaseService;
    }

    public String getLocatorCode(String isbn) {
        Book book = databaseService.lookup(isbn);
        if (book == null) book = webService.lookup(isbn);
        StringBuilder locator = new StringBuilder();
        locator.append(isbn.substring(isbn.length() - 4));
        locator.append(book.getAuthor().charAt(0));
        locator.append(book.getTitle().split(" ").length);
        return locator.toString();
    }
}

JUnit Test Class:
import com.java.tdd.locator.Book;
import com.java.tdd.locator.ExternalISBNDataService;
import com.java.tdd.locator.StockManager;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.junit.jupiter.MockitoExtension;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;

@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class StockManagementTests {

    private String isbn;
    @Mock
    private ExternalISBNDataService webService;
    @Mock
    private ExternalISBNDataService databaseService;
    @InjectMocks
    private StockManager stockManager;


    @BeforeEach
    public void setUp() {
        isbn = "0140177396";
    }

    @Test
    public void canGetACorrectLocatorCode() {
        when(webService.lookup(isbn)).thenReturn(new Book(isbn, "Of Mice And Men", "J. Steinbeck"));

        String locatorCode = stockManager.getLocatorCode(isbn);
        assertEquals("7396J4", locatorCode);
    }

    @Test
    public void databaseIsUsedIfDataIsPresent() {

        when(databaseService.lookup(isbn)).thenReturn(new Book(isbn, "Of Mice And Men", "J. Steinbeck"));
        when(webService.lookup(isbn)).thenReturn(new Book(isbn, "Of Mice And Men", "J. Steinbeck"));

        stockManager.getLocatorCode(isbn);

        verify(databaseService, times(1)).lookup(isbn);
        verify(webService, never()).lookup(anyString());
    }

    @Test
    public void webServiceIsUsedIfDataIsNotPresentInDatabase() {

        when(databaseService.lookup(isbn)).thenReturn(null);
        when(webService.lookup(isbn)).thenReturn(new Book(isbn, "Of Mice And Men", "J. Steinbeck"));

        stockManager.getLocatorCode(isbn);

        verify(databaseService, times(1)).lookup(isbn);
        verify(webService, times(1)).lookup(isbn);
    }
}


I’ve ensured that the StockManager class is correctly instantiated with both webService and dataService being injected.
I’m using @InjectMocks to inject the mocks into StockManager.
Despite this, the test is failing with the "Wanted but not invoked" error for the dataService.lookup(isbn) method.

Why is dataService.lookup(isbn) not being invoked as expected in my test, and how can I resolve this issue? Could this be due to the way dependencies of the same type are injected? cause I've already use @Mock and @InjectMocks in another test with one dependency and its working fine.

I think the problem here is that @ InjectMocks can not inject both classes because they are of the same type: ExternalISBNDataService.
I would remove @ InjectMocks annotation and manually add the constructor:
private StockManager stockManager; and in your setup stockManager = new StockManager(databaseService, webService);

What is the value of databaseService and webService in your class when running in the test? You can use a debugger or System.out.println(System.identityHashCode(...)) to find out. Do they point to the correct mock instances?

@MuratK. so there is no way to inject to mocks of the same type ?

@knittl I've tried to debug, but I found nothing

private String isbn;
private ExternalISBNDataService webService;
private ExternalISBNDataService databaseService;
private StockManager stockManager;


@BeforeEach
public void setUp() {
    isbn = "0140177396";

    webService = mock(ExternalISBNDataService.class);
    databaseService = mock(ExternalISBNDataService.class);
    stockManager = new StockManager(databaseService, webService);
}

this way it's working fine, but I don't now if we can do it with annotations

@Haitam-Elgharras what do you mean "you found nothing"? If you print the identity hash codes, do they match the expected hash codes and are they distinct?
